# Convert string variable to WaitCallback in ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, threadpool

Is it possible to pass string variable as a WaitCallback parameter in `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`

```
string myFunction="Go";
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyFunction);


public void Go(object obj)
{
       //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use reflection.

For example:

```
WaitCallback callback = (WaitCallback) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(WaitCallback), this, myFunction);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback);
```

To use a method in a different class, change `this` to the target instance. If you want to call a static method, use the overload of `CreateDelegate` which takes a `Type` as the second parameter rather than an object.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use reflection to get the method:

```
var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(myFunction, new Type[] { typeof(object) });
var d = (WaitCallback)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(WaitCallback), this, method);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(d);
```